# bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundle

I have been attempting to get RoR working with Passenger and Nginx. Man has it been an adventure. I have finally gotten the server running and it is hosting a test site, well sort of. I am running into an error with the assets. I cannot compile the application.js using `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. Here is the results with --trace:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby /Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'define.globalDomain.require.bind(define.globalDomain)')
  (in /Users/pstachof/.webserver/sites/stachtest1/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/uglifier-2.0.1/lib/uglifier.rb:167:in `really_compile'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/uglifier-2.0.1/lib/uglifier.rb:95:in `compile'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor='
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/tilt-1.3.7/lib/tilt/template.rb:77:in `render'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/pstachof/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-hea...]
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/pstachof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

If I set `config.assets.compile = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` and restart the server reload the site I receive the following in the production.log

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Started GET "/" for 98.156.89.130 at 2013-04-23 22:45:35 -0500
Processing by HomeController#welcome as HTML
  Rendered home/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application (10.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 77ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.js isn't precompiled):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Stachtest1</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__451492169_16346550'
```

If I remove the application.js file (of which I have not modified at all) from the assets/javascript directory and compile everything goes smoothly. I also tried compiling with the file in the assests/javascript directory but removed all of the text and it still failed.

I am using rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.3 and the following gems are installed locally

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
daemon_controller (1.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
hike (1.2.2)
i18n (0.6.1)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
json (1.7.7, 1.5.5)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.7.2)
passenger (3.0.19)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.9.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.7)
sass (3.2.8)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.3.7)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.0.1)
```

Here is the application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree
```

As I continue to play around with this set up, I have found that although it compiles the assets without the application.js file in the assets/javascript directory and it appears the css is compiling correctly it isn't displaying on the webpage after refreshing the server and site. If I put the style directly in the webpage it renders as it should.

Here are the associated files:
application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stachtest1</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        Does this work...
    </div>

    <%= yield %>

    <div style="border: 1px solid #000;">
        This is a test to see about some styles
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
.content
{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

public/application.css

```
.content{border:1px solid #999;padding:5px}
```

I am not sure if this is a separate question or not, if so I can pull it out but wanted to add it just in case.

I have sort of reached the end of my ideas. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If I am missing any information please let me know and I can fill in the gaps as best I can.

Thank you,
Patrick

Comment: Share your application.js file.

Comment: I have included the contents of the application.js file.

Comment: try to run with config.assets.precompile += ['application.js'] in config/environments/production.rb

Comment: If I add your suggestion and comment out config.assets.compile everything seems to start working again, thanks for the suggestion! However I cannot compile via rake since the application.js file is back in the assets/javascript dir. Also I was wondering if this causes a performance hit, is it compiling every time? The public/assets folder is not present.

Comment: no, no need to comment out config.assets.compile, just set it true, and in future, just include all your .css or .js files in config.assets.precompile

Comment: Find my production.rb file https://gist.github.com/shamithc/5449871

Comment: Ok, I think that I have it working, if you add an answer I will accept it. Thank you for your help. In the end I added config.assets.precompile += ['*.js', '*.css'] and  config.assets.compile = true and it all (even the css) works as expected. There does not appear to be any performance issues, however the site doesn't really do anything at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, lack of formatting changed my comment. The precompile statement should read: `config.assets.precompile += ['*.js', '*.css']`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Instead of

```
//= require_tree
```

With the dot at the end. Like in the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Answer (score 0):

I saw this same error after updating gems on an older already-deployed app. I narrowed it down to uglifier, having been upgraded from 1.3.0 to 2.0.1. According to its [README](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/blob/master/README.md) it needs a JS interpreter:

> Ensure that your environment has a JavaScript interpreter supported by ExecJS. Installing therubyracer gem is a safe choice and having node in PATH works too.

But it's not a hard dependency, so it didn't get caught by bundler. Not wanting to pursue that quite yet, I switched uglifier back to 1.3.0 in the Gemfile:

```
  gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
```

and all was well.

Comment: I gave that a shot but got the same result. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score -1):

check removing the below line form application.js

```
//= require_tree
```

`require_tree` loads all the files in app/javascripts dir recursively

If it works the there is some issue with one of the javascript file in app/assets/javascripts directory

check all the files in the directrory or

require the files one by one in application.js

```
//= require js_file_name
```

Comment: That was what I thought, but I actually took all the text out of the file, along with all of the //= require's and still received the error. Thank you for the suggestion though.